# Load iPython with custom packages imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, ipython

Does anyone know if it is possible to load ipython preloaded with custom packages please?

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows 8.

When I load a DOS prompt, I run ipython preloaded with pylab by typing

```
ipython --pylab
```

I've managed to create a shortcut to open a DOS prompt with this automatically fired, thus effectively creating a shortcut to iPython.

However, I'd like iPython to start preloaded with some of my custom packages. So I wonder if there is a way to  start iPython and automatically execute the following lines, say:

```
import package1 as my_package
import package2 as my_second_package
```

I've had a look online and there's some information on "magic" commands and scripts in iPython which looks like it might help, although I wasn't sure how to use this.

All guidance welcomed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a startup script.

First run `ipython locate profile` to find the profile folder. Then find a `startup` folder in there. Create a .py file (any name) in the startup folder with the imports you want, and IPython will run that whenever you it starts.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm on Windows 8  and the locate profile command returns an error. I've found a _ipython folder in my C:/Users/my_use folder although there's not "startup" folder inside and searching my C: struggles to find a startup folder too.

Comment: I tried adding a "startup" folder manually there and just inserting a print 'hello world' line to a  .py file, but it didn't work sadly.

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? It sounds like you might have an older version, so try updating to the latest.

Comment: I'm on 0.10.2 which I appreciate isn't the latest. I've been looking around and it seems that since I installed Python (x,y) things are located differently. For example, there's a startup folder in C:/Users/username/.xy/startups  but the scripts there only execute if you run ipython by first loading the Python (x,y) loader and clicking "run ipython". Since my motivation is to speed to command line operation of ipython, this is hardly a solution.

Comment: I wonder if there's any way to open an ipython terminal set to load a certain file. e.g. from the command line I can open ipython with numpy etc loaded by typing "ipython --pylab".

So if I could run "ipython --myscript" where myscipt is a .py file to load everything I need, that would  be useful. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Well, you can run `ipython -i myscript.py`. But 0.10.x is ancient now, so I'd really recommend you upgrade. The latest version of Python (x,y) has IPython 0.13.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the documentation, you will find out that IPython will run whatever is inside the file pointed by the `PYTHONSTARTUP` variable.

Create one, export the variable, and there you go.

References:

- http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#ipython-as-your-default-python-environment
- https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP